# Why does osx 64-bit asm syscall segfault

Tags: macos, assembly, segmentation-fault, x86-64, system-calls

I'm trying to write an x86-64 hello world in assembly on OSX, but whenever I make a syscall to write, it's segfaulting.  I've tried the equivalent syscall via Gnu C inline assembly and it works, so I'm thoroughly confused:

```
        .section        __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
        .globl  _main
        .align  4, 0x90
_main:
        .cfi_startproc
        movq 0x2000004, %rax
        movq 1, %rdi
        leaq _hi(%rip), %rsi
        movq 12, %rdx
        syscall

        xor   %rax, %rax
        ret
        .cfi_endproc

        .section        __DATA,__data
        .globl  _hi
_hi:
        .asciz   "Hello world\n"
```

This is based off of the following Gnu C, which works:

```
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char *hw = "Hello World\n";
  unsigned long long result;
  asm volatile ("movq %1, %%rax\n"
       "movq %2, %%rdi\n"
       "movq %3, %%rsi\n"
       "movq %4, %%rdx\n"
       "syscall\n"
       : "=rax" (result)
       : "Z" (0x2000004),
         "Z" (1),
         "r" (hw),
         "Z" (12)
       : "rax", "rdi", "rsi", "rdx");
}
```

The C block when compiled generates the following asm:

```
        .section        __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
        .globl  _main
        .align  4, 0x90
_main:                                  ## @main
        .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
        pushq   %rbp
Ltmp2:
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp3:
        .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp4:
        .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
        leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rcx
        movq    %rcx, -8(%rbp)
        ## InlineAsm Start
        movq $33554436, %rax
movq $1, %rdi
movq %rcx, %rsi
movq $12, %rdx
syscall

        ## InlineAsm End
        movq    %rcx, -16(%rbp)
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        popq    %rbp
        ret
        .cfi_endproc

        .section        __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
L_.str:                                 ## @.str
        .asciz   "Hello World\n"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is on these few lines:

```
movq 0x2000004, %rax
movq 1, %rdi
leaq _hi(%rip), %rsi
movq 12, %rdx
```

Be aware that with at&t syntax that if you want to use constants you *MUST* prefix them with a **$** (dollar sign) otherwise you are referencing memory addresses. Without a $ sign your value is an immediate indirect address.

For instance:

```
movq 0x2000004, %rax
```

attempts to move the quadword from memory address `0x2000004` and place it in `%rax`.

You probably just have to modify your code to look like:

```
movq $0x2000004, %rax
movq $1, %rdi
leaq _hi(%rip), %rsi
movq $12, %rdx
```

Notice that I have added a dollar sign to the beginning of each constant.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple 64-bit "Hello World" (or Hello StackOverflow) in this case. It should build on OSX. Give it a try:

```
section .data
    string1 db  0xa, "  Hello StackOverflow!!!", 0xa, 0xa, 0
    len equ $ - string1

section .text
    global _start

    _start:
    ; write string to stdout
        mov     rax, 1              ; set write to command
        mov     rsi, string1        ; string1 to source index
        mov     rdi, rax            ; set destination index to 1 (stdout) already in rax
        mov     rdx, len            ; set length in rdx
        syscall                     ; call kernel

        ; exit
        xor     rdi,rdi             ; zero rdi (rdi hold return value)
        mov     rax, 0x3c           ; set syscall number to 60 (0x3c hex)
        syscall                     ; call kernel

; **Compile/Output**
;
;     $ nasm -felf64 -o hello-stack_64.o hello-stack_64.asm
;     $ ld -o hello-stack_64 hello-stack_64.o

;     $ ./hello-stack_64
;
;       Hello StackOverflow!!!
```